# How to get varied results in a cell based on a variety of inputs in a different cell

Tags: excel

I have a column with a drop down list of options. Based on the results of this selection I would like a cell in the following column to enter a corresponding value.

In other words, If I have selected 'Porridge' from my drop down list in A1, I would like it to automatically update B1 with £2.00. But if I select 'Apple' in A1, I would like it to update B1 with £1.00 and so on for a number of results.

Answer (score 0):

How about this as your formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,{"Porridge",2;"Apple",1;"And so no",3},2,FALSE)
```

If you want to return text values instead of numbers then:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,{"Porridge","£2.00";"Apple","£1.00";"And so no","£3.00"},2,FALSE)
```